# Vim timestamp in insert mode results in mapped key

Tags: vim, timestamp, keymapping

I put following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <F3> i<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR>
```

In normal mode, it works as expected i.e. inserts timestamp.
In insert mode, however, I get `<F3>` inserted. What am I doing wrong and how to get it working?

**UPDATE**: I realized that everything works as expected in Gvim, the problem is only with terminal vim (I tried lxterminal and gnome-terminal). If it helps, I have similar issue with remapping Esc character, works fine in Gvim but not in Vim.

**UPDATE 2**: Though I can not rule out some other change I might have done to the system, it is highly likely that upgrading to newer vim version made the problem go away. Remapping Esc also works now i.e. terminal Vim (version 8.1, 2018 May 18) behaves as Gvim.

Comment: It works as expected here. `imap` is a recursive mapping, though, so it may expand other mappings. See if replacing it with `inoremap` helps.

Comment: Thanks @romainl but inoremap does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you had `:set paste` enabled. *Paste mode* prevents  any insert and command-line mode mappings from taking effect. It is meant to be entered only temporarily before pasting text into the terminal (usually via a key defined in `'pastetoggle'`. This is only necessary in the terminal (and only those that don't have *bracketed paste mode*), GVIM can detect pastes on its own. This would then affect *any* insert mode mappings. You can check via

```
:verbose set paste?
```